# Matching histogram with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
nutsshp_df=gpd.read_file(nuts_shp)
indmapdata=nutsshp_df.set_index('NUTS_ID').join(ind_rg)
vmin = ind_rg[year].min()
vmax = ind_rg[year].max()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,12))
ax.set_xlim(xmin=-11,xmax=32)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=34,ymax=72)
ax.axis('off')

indmapdata.plot(column=year,cmap='rainbow',linewidth=0.8,ax=ax,edgecolor='0.8')


#-------------    
#Colorbar    
#-------------

maxval=int(((math.ceil(ind_rg[year].max()/1000))*1000)+1000)

divider=make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
axbar=divider.append_axes("right",'5%',pad='7%')
axhist=divider.append_axes("right",'20%',pad='7%')

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='rainbow',norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin,vmax=maxval))
cbar=plt.colorbar(sm,cax=axbar,orientation='vertical')
axbar.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

#-------------
#Histogram
#-------------

indgcyr=ind_rg[year]

bins=[*range(0,maxval,1000)]
N,bins,patches=axhist.hist(indgcyr,bins=bins,orientation='horizontal',log=True)
norm=Normalize(bins.min(),bins.max())    
for bin,patch in zip(bins,patches):
    color=cm.rainbow(norm(bin))
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
```

As you can see, while both the colorbar and the histogram have the same max value `(maxval)`, the histogram doesn't start at the origin, and the scales in both plots don't "match". How could I fix this problem? I would really appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `axhist.margins(y=0)`? Or `axhist.set_ylim(0, maxval)`?

Comment: Maybe you could also set `bins=[*range(0,maxval+1,1000)]`? Otherwise, the bins would stop just before the maximal value.

Comment: Awesome! The combination of `axhist.margins(y=0)` and `bins=[*range(0,maxval+1,1000)]` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Just checked with `axhist.set_ylim(0, maxval)`. Also works without doing `bins=[*range(0,maxval+1,1000)]`. Thanks again for your help.